# Populate dropdown box from array and display with php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to populate a dropdown box with contents of the color array then display in a php file. Also display radio button selection on php file. I can not figure it out. I havent even started with the display of the array in the php file because I cant even populate the dropdown box. Any help would be much appreciated.

## My HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$Color = array("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Cyan", "Magenta", "Yellow");
$Food = array("Barbeque", "Chinese", "Japanese", "Thai", "Steak", "Vegan", "Mexican");
?>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Lab 08</title></head> 
 <body> 
 <h2>Data Collection</h2><p> 
 <form method="get" action="test.php">
 <table> 
 <p>Select your favorite color.</p>
 <select name=Color> 


<?php

foreach($Color as $col)
    {
    echo "<option value=\"$col\">". $col ."</option>\n";    
}

?>
</select>
 <p>Select your favorite type of food.</p>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Barbeque">Barbeque<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Chinese">Chinese<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Japanese">Japanese<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Thai">Thai<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Steak">Steak<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Vegan">Vegan<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Food" value="Mexican">Mexican<br>
 <p></p>
 <tr><td>Enter your first name:</td><td><input name="First" type="text" /></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>Enter your last name:</td><td><input name="Last" type="text" /></td></tr> 

 <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value ="Submit"/></td></tr> 
 </table> 
 </form> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

## My PHP file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    $First = (isset($_GET['First']) ? $_GET['First'] : null);
    $Last = (isset($_GET['Last']) ? $_GET['Last'] : null);
    $Color = (isset($_GET['Color']) ? $_GET['Color'] : null);
    $Food = (isset($_GET['Food']) ? $_GET['Food'] : null);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Lab 08</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php


if ($Color) {
echo "<p>$Color</p>";
    }
    else if (empty($Color)) {
    echo "<p>Please enter your favorite color.</p>";
    }
if ($Food)  {   
echo "<p>$Food</p>";
    }
    else if (empty($Food))  {
    echo "<p>Please enter your favorite food.</p>";
    }
if (!is_numeric($First) and (!empty($First)))   {
echo "<p>$First</p>";
    }
    else if (empty($First)) {
    echo "<p>Please enter first name.</p>";
    }
    else if (is_numeric($First))    {
    echo "<p>First name must be letters.</p>";
    }

if (!is_numeric($Last) and (!empty($Last)))     {
echo "<p>$Last</p>";
    }
    else if (empty($Last))  {
    echo "<p>Please enter last name.</p>";
    }
```

Comment: Yes. The first is an HTML file and the second is a php file. The Dropdown box is being populated on your computer?

Comment: I have it saved as an HTML file. That must be it. Ill try it when I get home. Second part of my question, how do I display it in the second file and how do I associate second array with radio button selection and display it in second file?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
//$row = null; 
while ($row = $col){

    echo "<option value=\"$row\">". $row ."</option>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: When the page is displayed in the browser the page source isnt closing the php block where the array is. Your suggestion didnt work either, I think because of the reason above.

Answer (score 0):

You write in your comment, that

> [...] The first is an HTML file and the second is a php file. [...]

You cannot run PHP code in a HTML file. Change the file extension of your first file from `.html` to `.php` to fix this.